# How to show that $X_n$ fails to converge to $0$ in $\mathcal{L}_1$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Suppose $W_1,W_2,....$ are independent and identically distributed random variables such that $P(W_1=0)=P(W_1=2) =1/2$. For each $n=1,2,3...$ define the random variable $X_n = W_1.W_2...W_n$. Show that

a) $X_n  \rightarrow 0$ a.s as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

b) $X_n$ fails to converge to $0$ in $\mathcal{L}_1$ as $ n \rightarrow \infty$?

For part a), firstly I showed that the random variable $X_n$ is a martingale and $\sup_n E(|X_n|)< \infty$.

Then $X_n$ converges to $X$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ $a.s$. To show that $X=0$, By strong law of large numbers,
$$\log(X_n)= \log\left(W_1.W_2....W_n\right)=n\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\log(W_i)\right)  \rightarrow -\infty~~ a.s$$
This implies that $X_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$  a.s.

For part c) I need to show that $X_n$ is not uniform integrable. I am not sure how to start this problem. Can anyone give me some hint for this part?

Is the solution of part b) is correct?

Comment: It isn't true that $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(W_i) = n\log(W_i)$, but anyway since $W_i$ does not converge to $1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(W_i)$ must diverge, and since $X_n$ converge to $X \in [0,\infty)$ it actually must be the case that $\sum_{i=1}^n \log(W_i)$ diverges to $-\infty$. For the second part, simply note that $\mathbb E[X_n] = 1$ hence  $\mathbb E[|X_n-0|] = \mathbb E[X_n] \not \to 0$.

Comment: I see. You used that $E[|X_n|]$ does not converges to the $E[|X|]$ which is zero in this case. This implies it fails to converge to $0$ in $\mathcal{L}_1$.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n\to 0$ a.s. because $\mathsf{P}(W_n=0 \text{ for some }n\ge 1)=1$. (In fact, $W_n=0$ i.o. a.s.) Now, the uniform integrability of $\{X_n\}$ would imply the $L^1$ convergence, and the latter fails by part (b).